# selecting one of several elements that differ in attribute

Tags: xslt, attributes, conditional-statements

I'm an experienced programmer, but a novice to XSLT and am finding it quite baffling. I apologize if this is a question that's been asked before, but I'm so frustrated by XSLT that I'm not even sure what to search for...

I have a problem that if a certain XML element appears only once, I want its contents output, but if it occurs more than once, I want only the contents of those that have a certain attribute.

For example, suppose I have one XML file (call it "file 1") that contains

```
<food>
    <snack>Chips</snack>
    <snack type="nuts">Peanuts</snack>
</food>
```

and another XML file ("file 2") that contains

```
<food>
    <snack>Cheese puffs</snack>
</food>
```

I need an XSLT that outputs only "Peanuts" (but not "Chips") upon processing file 1, but still outputs "Cheese puffs" for file 2 (i.e. I can't just select only those  elements that have a "type" attribute, that would be too easy).

This is probably simple, but I'm stuck...

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution based on the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design patterns -- the overriding of the identity rule. Explanation is also provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
   "*[snack/@type]/snack[not(@type)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**produces the wanted results in both cases**.

**Explanation**:

1. **The identity rule/template copies every node "as-is"**.
2. **The second template is overriding the identity template** for any `snack` element without a `type` attribute that has sibling `snack` elements that have a `type` attribute. This template has empty body, which effectively "deletes" the matched element from (being copied to) the output.

Comment: Brilliant! Works great! Thanks. Never in my wildest imaginings would I have thought of solving the problem with 2 templates: one that does almost the opposite of what I want, and the other that literally does nothing. Why do XSLT idioms have to be so counter-intuitive :-)

Answer (score 0):

> if a certain XML element appears only once, I want its contents output, but if it occurs more than once, I want only the contents of those that have a certain attribute.

A direct translation of that would be

```
if (count(snack) = 1) then snack else snack[@type='nuts']
```

which is valid XPath 2.0 syntax - if you need to do it in 1.0 then it translates fairly directly (though verbosely) into an equivalent xsl:choose.

If you want something even more concise than the above, you can also write in XPath 2.0

```
(snack[@type='nuts'], snack)[1]
```

which builds a list containing first the snacks with type='nuts', then all the snacks, and then selects the first item from this list.